# MATCH AGAINST in MySQL not showing records when search for string less than 4 chars

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search, against

I am using FULLTEXT index on a column and when I use MATCH....AGAINST in boolean mode for any search term which is less than 4 characters in length then it doesn't return any records. And when I use LIKE then it does return records.
What could be the problem? Is it because of some MySQL limitation like it doesn't index words that are less than 4 chars in length or some limitation specific to FULLTEXT index?

Thanks

Comment: Try to run `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` like this `AGAINST ('database' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);`

Comment: I used "WITH QUERY EXPANSION" but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `ft_min_word_len` system variable. That defines the minimum length of words to be indexed.

**Update**: Ok I did some tests with `ft_min_word_len=3`

First a test table

```
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`table1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  FULLTEXT INDEX `Name` (`name` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Next some test data:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'This has led in it');
INSERT INTO `test`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'Led is nice');
INSERT INTO `test`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('3', 'Leds are nicer');
INSERT INTO `test`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('4', 'Nothin here');
INSERT INTO `test`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('5', 'some word which does not exists: abcleddef');
```

Running this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`.`table1` t1 WHERE match(`t1`.`name`) against ('led' in boolean mode)
```

Returns this:

```
1   This has led in it
2   Led is nice
```

Running this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`.`table1` t1 WHERE match(`t1`.`name`) against ('led*' in boolean mode)
```

Returns this:

```
1   This has led in it
2   Led is nice
3   Leds are nicer
```

So FT search works as expected. Any chance the word you are trying to find is actually something like `leds` and not the single word `led`?

Comment: Let's say if that ft_main_word_len is set to 4 then why when I run the same query with LIKE operator bring results but not MATCH AGAINST? Is it because LIKE doesn't use FULLTEXT index like MATCH AGAINST?

Comment: As far as I know `LIKE` only uses a normal index (if there is one) and falls back to table scan.

Comment: Ok I changed "ft_main_word_len" value to 3, then restarted MySQL, then drop FULLTEXT index in both tables, then recreated FULLTEXT index, and then ran that query again but still no luck. Although when I run the same query with LIKE '%key%' then it works.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: The query is something like: 

`SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.recordid AND match('t1.title') against ('led' in boolean mode) AND match('t2.name') against ('led' in boolean mode)`  


But if I use this query then it brings result:  

`SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.recordid AND t1.title like '%led%' and t2.name like '%led%'`  

And the following query too brings result:  


`SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.recordid AND match('t1.title') against ('led*' in boolean mode) AND match('t2.name') against ('led*' in boolean mode)`

Comment: Based on my tests I think the problem is the text you are trying to find. Maybe your expectations as to how FT search works are wrong?